# Listing all images in a directory using PHP

Tags: php, image

I have the code below that lists all the images in a folder, the problem is that it finds some files **( a . and a ..)** that I am not sure what they are so I am not sure how to prevent them from showing up. I am on a **windows XP machine**, any help would be great, thanks.

> Errors: Warning: rename(images/.,images/.) [function.rename]: No error
>   in C:\wamp\www\Testing\listPhotosA.php on line 14
>
> Warning: rename(images/..,images/..) [function.rename]: No error in
>   C:\wamp\www\Testing\listPhotosA.php on line 14

Code:

```
<?php
define('IMAGEPATH', 'images/');

if (is_dir(IMAGEPATH)){
    $handle = opendir(IMAGEPATH);
}
else{
    echo 'No image directory';
}

$directoryfiles = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    $newfile = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);
    rename(IMAGEPATH . $file, IMAGEPATH . $newfile);
    $directoryfiles[] = $newfile;
}

foreach($directoryfiles as $directoryfile){
    if(strlen($directoryfile) > 3){
    echo '<img src="' . IMAGEPATH . $directoryfile . '" alt="' . $directoryfile . '" /> <br>';
    }
}

closedir($handle); ?>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I like PHP's [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) function.

```
foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
    echo basename($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great! i didnt realize PHP had a glob, that worked great. I still dont know what the . and .. are that opendir was finding. ANy ideas? I'm just curious for the future

Comment: '.' is the current directory, and '..' is the parent directory.  I don't know why opendir was showing them.

Comment: What if the imagepath contains brackets i.e.`[byUser]` ?

Comment: @BubuDaba: Not sure.  Try it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it doesn't work because [glob](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) parses the string as a regex pattern so regex chars break it. I tried escaping it with [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-quote.php) but it didn't work too. I dunno why, I'm not expert

Comment: @BubuDaba: You might want to ask that as your own question, see what others have to say.

Comment: That regex will return all files, and glob is case sensitive so you must do something like `glob($path.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}',GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: $images = glob('public/'.$folder.'/*/*{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
is better for subdirectories

Answer (score 12):

[glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is case sensitive and the wildcard `*` will return all files, so I specified the extension here so you don't have to do the filtering work

```
$d = 'path/to/images/';
foreach(glob($d.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}',GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
    $imag[] =  basename($file);
}
```

Comment: $images = glob('public/'.$folder.'/*/*{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
is better for subdirectories

Answer (score 6):

Use glob function.

```
<?php
define('IMAGEPATH', 'images/');
foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
    $imag[] =  basename($filename);
}
print_r($imag);
?>
```

You got all images in array format

Answer (score 2):

To get all jpg images in all dirs and subdirs inside a folder:

```php
function getAllDirs($directory, $directory_seperator) {
  $dirs = array_map(function ($item) use ($directory_seperator) {
    return $item . $directory_seperator;
  }, array_filter(glob($directory . '*'), 'is_dir'));
  foreach ($dirs AS $dir) {
    $dirs = array_merge($dirs, getAllDirs($dir, $directory_seperator));
  }
  return $dirs;
}

function getAllImgs($directory) {
  $resizedFilePath = array();
  foreach ($directory AS $dir) {
    foreach (glob($dir . '*.jpg') as $filename) {
        array_push($resizedFilePath, $filename);
    }
  }
  return $resizedFilePath;
}

$directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/images/";
$directory_seperator = "/";
$allimages = getAllImgs(getAllDirs($directory, $directory_seperator));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using balphp's scan_dir function:
https://github.com/balupton/balphp/blob/765ee3cfc4814ab05bf3b5512b62b8b984fe0369/lib/core/functions/_scan_dir.funcs.php

`scan_dir($dirPath, array('pattern'=>'image'));`

Will return an array of all files that are images in that path and all subdirectories, using a `$path => $filename` structure. To turn off scanning subdirectories, set the `recurse` option to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to read images from the folder.

```
function readDataFromImageFolder() {

$imageFolderName = 14;
$base = dirname(__FILE__);
$dirname = $base.DS.'images'.DS.$imageFolderName.DS;
$files = array();

if (!file_exists($dirname)) {
    echo "The directory $dirname not exists.".PHP_EOL;
    exit;
} else {
    echo "The directory $dirname exists.".PHP_EOL;
    $dh  = opendir( $dirname );

    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        if ($filename === '.' || $filename === '..') continue;
        $files[] = $dirname.$filename;
    }
    uploadImages( $files );
}
}
```

Please click here for detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/read-images-folder-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPP oriented [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(IMAGEPATH) as $fileInfo) {
    // Removing dots
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }

    // You have all necessary data in $fileInfo
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    if (
        ($file == '.')||
        ($file == '..')
    ) {
        continue;
    }
    $newfile = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);
    rename(IMAGEPATH . $file, IMAGEPATH . $newfile);
    $directoryfiles[] = $newfile;
}
```